# How to encrypt fields in XML document with PHP and RSA / Triple DES

Tags: php, xml, security, rsa, tripledes

I am developing an application for schools in South Africa which is required to submit data in XML format to the State IT Agency for statistical processing. I am currently generating the XML files using PHP's `DOMDocument` class.

My files have gone through a first stage verification process. The next stage is to implement encryption and compression of the XML files. The compression is a simple GZip so no worries there.

The specification document indicates that both RSA Encryption is used (I will be issued RSA keys to implement into the software) as well as some form of symmetrical encryption such as Triple DES (although this is an "example" and any of the algorithms at `http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core` can be implemented). If I understand this correctly, the RSA encryption is to encode a symmetrical key which is used for the actual encryption of the fields.

The specification document also says "Encryption of an XML file can be performed either on the whole file or on certain elements." I'm not quite sure which is easier, at this stage and so answers to either will suffice!

The requirement is, I assume, to encrypt the contents of the XML tags and not the names (as in `http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlenc-core/#sec-eg-Element-Content-Character`).

I apologise if this seems vague. It is currently all the information I have and the contacts at the Agency are happy to say that the (VisualBasic .NET) code samples should explain everything... If you want to examine this code sample, you are welcome to have a look at the Word document in the following ZIP file, from about page 213 onwards. http://www.sita.co.za/doe_lurits/DEVS-00118%20Rev%201.2%2012%20Jan%202009.zip

If anyone can help or point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @The Rook I don't disagree. Any of the supported encryption methods can be used though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just encrypt the XML file using XMLSec Encryption. The following library should handle all the details for you,

http://code.google.com/p/xmlseclibs/

Comment: Thanks: this seems to do exactly what I need it to do. I will investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

See [`openssl_encrypt`](http://php.net/openssl_encrypt) for symmetric encryption and [`openssl_public_encrypt`](http://php.net/openssl_public_encrypt)/[`openssl_private_decrypt`](http://php.net/openssl_private_decrypt) for asymmetric encryption.

Comment: @Philip If you choose to encrypt the XML you can wrap the XML document in another XML document where you include the public key (or a certificate), the encrypted symmetric key and the encrypted payload each on separate elements, possibly base64 encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you can either encrypt the entire document or just the contents of certain "sensitive" tags.  Encrypting the entire document would probably be the easiest way to go.

As for the RSA/3DES thing - you are almost certainly right.  You would encrypt the document with 3DES, then encrypt your 3DES key with their RSA public key.

So, seems like what you need to do is just generate the document, zip it, then encrypt the zipped results with 3DES.

Comment: Thanks, Eric. The next step is to know how this is ultimately structured in XML. How do I indicate what the symmetric key is? Encrypting the entire file is straightforward enough and placing it in the appropriate <EncryptedData> structure is fine. That would have been done using Triple DES. But somewhere, I have to have the key?

Answer (score 0):

The Symmetric-encrypted-document-plus-PK-encrypted-key architecture is essentially PGP. Would OpenPGP be acceptable to your customer?

Comment: You are not wrong, but I am writing an interface for data transfer into an existing system. Thus I must comply with them :-)